# Integrating Google Drive API and Picasa API in iOS application

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, picasa

i am working on an iOS application in which i have to integrate Google Drive API's and Picasa Web albums API. For Google Drive i am using " https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/"" Google Drive iOS API and for Picasa i am using Picasa Web Albums Data API "GDATA". Now when i integrate both API's in my application i found 204 duplicates are creating. I show them on the log like:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.request_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.connection_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.downloadedData_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.downloadPath_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.temporaryDownloadPath_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.downloadFileHandle_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.credential_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.proxyCredential_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.postData_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.postStream_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.loggedStreamData_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.response_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.completionBlock_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.receivedDataBlock_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.sentDataBlock_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.retryBlock_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.userData_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.properties_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.runLoopModes_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.fetchHistory_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.cookieStorage_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.authorizer_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.service_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.serviceHost_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.thread_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.retryTimer_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.comment_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.log_ in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _GTMAssertSelectorNilOrImplementedWithArgs in:
    /Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMReadMonitorInputStream.o)
    /Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMReadMonitorInputStream.o)
ld: 204 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am not getting the way by which i can remove this duplicates.i had tried my best but can't succedded. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did You import any .m files if so clear that and import .h file

try this if that is not the case

- build settings
- Open "Search path"
- Open "Framework search path"
- now,double click on path located
- there are two paths like

  `$(inherited)`

  `"$(SRCROOT)/../../../Data/myCodes/He/ed/Nav"`

remove all data of first and second path..That's it.

Note : It works only if above two options available in Framework Search Path (Working fine with some cases / UNDO if not work)

Comment: This is not an answer that look like comment you have to put as a comment instead of answer.

Comment: Can u see my reputation ??

Comment: sir, its not working both are Google API's ,so they create issue. Can we changes the name of the variables.